# How to create a background image in android with two colors divided diagonally?

Tags: android, background, drawable

http://www.anbg.gov.au/images/flags/misc/semaphore.gif
I want to create an image like the one I postet but with xml file. I hope I'm clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create it using drawable xml's shapes.

The available shapes are :

> ```
>     "rectangle"   A rectangle that fills the containing View. This is the default shape.
>     "oval"    An oval shape that fits the dimensions of the containing View.
>     "line"    A horizontal line that spans the width of the containing View. This shape requires the <stroke> element to define
> ```
>
> the width of the line.
>           "ring"    A ring shape.
>
> [Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

You can use canvas and draw it.